# Firefox loses app tabs when I shut down my computer sometimes

Tags: firefox, windows-vista

When I shut down my computer sometimes my app tabs do not reopen in Firefox and I need to remake all of them which is pretty annoying. I don't know if this is a common bug it might be specific to my computer.

I run Vista x64 and it just seems to still have quite a bit of problems. Sometimes when I command it to shut down it does not simply showing shut down loading for hours so I need to manually turn it off. I think that might be messing up Firefox but I'm not sure.

I also found a related [thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625016) on Bugzilla about this problem but I don't think it's the same issue as it only happens when I shut down my computer.

Comment: Do you definitely only have a single firefox Window open when this happens?

Comment: I know for sure that I have no windows open when the computer is shutting off but I might open more then one window of firefox once i restart my computer. This is not however what the bug states

Comment: I find app tabs to be easy to lose.  The common way is to close firefox in the "wrong" sequence, where you close the app tab window of firefox before another window which doesn't have app tabs open, and firefox remembers the app tab settings from teh second window - ie it remembers you have none.  It seems like firefox may not be closing correctly, and the app tabs are not being saved.  Can you try closing firefox and then check in Task Manager that no firefox.exe processes remain?

Comment: yes the app tabs can be lost by closing in the incorrect order but this is not what is happening here. It is true that sometimes firefox remains in my processes after exit and i have to manually terminate it but it restores properly with app tabs on. I have a problem only after shutting down my computer. (luckly)